# SQL Error The turnaround time has expired

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a sqlServer problem in my .net MVC application

Well the error is thrown from the da.fill(ds) line :

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(req, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
```

and this is the error :

```
 The turnaround time has expired. The timeout elapsed before the end of the operation or the server does not respond. '
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult = 0x80131904
 Message = The execution time has expired. The timeout elapsed before the end of the operation or the server does not respond.
 Source = .Net SqlClient Data Provider
  Procedure tree:
 <Can not Evaluate Exception Procedure Call Tree>
```

Well i found the main problem and it is an sql request :

```
 SELECT  * 
    from Nbre_enq_livreur   
 where (nb_enq >= 3) and T_PHONET = 207 and t_groupement = 25  
   GROUP BY T_PHONET,livreur,Init_Maglivreur,nb_enq,t_groupement
   Well it is correct but t_groupement and t_phonet don't want to work togther
```

I waited for 15 min and still circuling wwhen launching the request in MSMS

Any help and ty

Answer (score 0):

If your query needs more than the default 30 seconds, you might want to set the [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) higher. To do that you'll change it after you instantiated the DataAdapter on the SelectCommand property of that instance, like so:

```
//set the CommandTimeout
da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;  // seconds
```

Code will be

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(req, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;  // seconds
da.Fill(ds);
return ds;
```

Comment: Well i already used this solution but it is not good because i have to wait for 10 min and more .I edited the question for further ionformation.